# combine model on Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have couple of questions about combine model on forge viewer (load list urn to 1 viewer):

1. when i combine model. i only can get data from 1 main model in that combine. for instance, 
   `var instanceTree = GlobalViewer.model.getData().instanceTree;`
   `var allDbIdsStr = Object.keys(instanceTree.nodeAccess.dbIdToIndex);`
   `var list = allDbIdsStr.map(function (id) { return parseInt(id) });`
   list will return all dbid of main model, how can i access all data of all model when i combine?
2. what is the unique id for object in combine model. i do some function with dbid and i realize it can appear in others model too.
3. When i combine 3d model(revit) with 2d model(autocad). it has 2 case: if 3d model load first i can rotate like normal, if 2d model load first i cant rotate the model any more. how can i force it always can rotate?
4. Autocad unit seems different with model in viewer. it always scale down compare with the model. how can i fix that?

Appreciate any comments,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding #1: `viewer.model` obviously only references one of the models (I believe it's the last one you loaded), but you can use `viewer.getVisibleModels()` or `viewer.getHiddenModels()` to get other loaded models as well.

Regarding #2: `dbIDs` are only unique within a single model; many of the viewer methods accept an additional parameter specifying the model on which to operate, for example, you could say `viewer.select([123, 456], oneOfMyModels)`.

Regarding #3: that's a good question; loading a 2D model first puts the viewer into 2D viewing mode (where only zoom and pan is allowed); if you know you will be working with 3D models, I'd recommend always loading those first

Regarding #4: yes, each loaded model can have different units; when loading a model using the `loadDocumentNode` method you can specify additional options (for example, a placement transform for the loaded geometries), and one of them is an object called `applyScaling`, for example, like so:

```js
viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewable, {
    applyScaling: { to: 'mm' }
});
```

Comment: Regarding #3: after i check again. it seems random between 2D mode and 3D mode. i try to loading 3D model first but it still show 2D mode, sometime i reload viewer again and it show 3D mode. little bit confuse

Comment: Try manually disabling the 2D mode in the navigation logic using `viewer.navigation.setIs2D(false);`.

Comment: i found the reason why it random. i forget that ``loadDocumentNode`` is promise so although i already place list urn in order but it still not working. anw i cant find method ``viewer.navigation.setIs2D()`` in documentation, and it return identified too. Thanks you

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest version of the viewer (7.*). It's possible that the `setIs2D` method wasn't available in earlier versions.