# How to make sure the building is loaded in the right orientation?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I use the grid on the scene. The Building A (first image) setup is to be expected. But when I uploaded Building B, the orientation didn't match. Do I have to set it up in Revit ? or can I do it programatically.

[image: building B]

[image: building A]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every model you load into the viewer is coming with its own metadata such as:

- what is the "up" direction of the model
- what is the offset of the model from the origin
- what units is the model defined in

By default the viewer honors all these settings which means that, for example, if you load a Revit model that is defined in feet (and uses the Z-axis as the "up" direction), and then an Inventor model that is defined in meters (and uses the Y-axis as the "up" direction), the two models will have different scale and orientation.

To work around this issue, when loading (aggregating) multiple models in Forge Viewer, you can override any unit scaling, offset, or general 4x4 transformation that is applied to each model. For more details, look at https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/multi-model-refresher.

Comment: Hi @petr-broz
I checked the link you provided in you answer, however I cannot see where and how to override the unit scale when loading second model.
in my case I have a model which is in Feet and the other in Millimeters. when I open both in Navisworks they are in correct place and scale. but in Forge they are in different places / scales.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that piece. Units are defined using the `applyScaling` property which you can set to values like `m`, `meters`, `ft`, `feet`, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Petr-broz, I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64023659/combine-model-on-autodesk-forge/64026087#64026087
Thanks for the reply anyways :)